# Ubuntu "Server" Help

Tags: 12.04

I've setup an Ubuntu Server (I plan on using it as one), and I have already set it up to start in command line so it runs more efficiently.

I still want to have access to the GUI if I need it, because I am fairly new to this.

Basically, I want to make it so that I can press the power button, and when it starts up, I want to be able to access the command line from my windows machine WITHOUT having to put in the root password into the Linux machine.

I would still like it to be locked when I access it from the windows machine though, for security. I would also really like to start the GUI if I absolutely need it for something, but since I have file access through the network, I don't think I will be using it much.

I need to know what I need to do with both my Windows machine and my Linux machine (obviously), so if someone has a solution to all of these, that would be great.

I also want the machine to run as efficiently as possible, so as long as I can control everything from my Windows machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Sincerely, nothing clear about what exactly do you want... Please ask one question per time and make it clear.

Comment: Standard "destop" interfaces are, IMO, of little to no valuse on a server. Most of server managemnet involves editing files, installing packages, or starting / stoping services, all of which can easily be done from the command line using PuTTY. If you "need" a graphical interface, I highly suggest you use a web interface such as webmin.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a GUI for the usages you describe.  You definitely don't need X or GNOME or anything like that.  I recommend that you enable an SSH server on your Ubuntu box by typing `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

Then, install PuTTY on your Windows box [Link](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).  With this configuration you can remote into your server from your windows box.

If you absolutely need X access, you can configure PuTTY to forward X to your Windows machine, but you'll need to install an X server like Xming for this to work [Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/%E2%80%8E)